# Calculate a fictional animal based on real animals

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, animals

Given the following equations:
[image: animalchaos]

With the following data:

[image: elephant]

Could you find the answer?

[image: question]

*Note: the icons resemble the animals, you don't have to look at (for example) the colors how the icons are painted, or other details.*

To show these cute little animals, I used the icons of the following website:
[Animals icons created by Freepik - Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/animals)

Comment: the swallow and half dragonfly makes things interesting

Comment: @justhalf, what's wrong with the dragonfly, it's justhalf, same as you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Based on the chosen animals, it seems likely that two values play in: the number of legs and the number of wings of each animal. Using this hypothesis we can express each animal as a value using the placeholders $A$ and $B$ for the value of each leg and wing respectively:
>
>  \begin{array}{lll}\text{Elephant}=4A\qquad & \text{Dog}=4A\qquad & \text{Eagle} = 2A+2B \\ \text{Fly}=6A+2B & \text{Dragonfly} = 6A+4B & \text{Swallow} = 2A+2B \\ \text{Spider} = 8A & \text{Snake} = 0 \end{array}
>  And then validating that each of the equations hold:
>  *Horizontal equations (top-to-bottom):*
>  \begin{align}4A + 4A + (2A + 2B) &= 8A + (2A + 2B) &\checkmark \\(6A + 2B) + (6A + 4B) - (2A + 2B) &= 2(8A) &\Rightarrow B=\frac{3}{2}A \\8A + 0 - 4A &= 4A &\checkmark \\(2A+2B) + (3(4A)+4A) + \frac{1}{2}(6A+4B) &= 2(6A+2B) + (2A+2B) + 4A &\Rightarrow B=\frac{3}{2}A \\\end{align}
>
>  *Vertical equations (left-to-right):*
>  \begin{align}4A + (6A+2B) - 8A &= 2A+2B &\checkmark \\4A + (6A+4B) + 0 &= 3(4A) + 4A &\Rightarrow B=\frac{3}{2}A \\(2A+2B) + (2A+2B) - 4A &= \frac{1}{2}(6A+4B) &\Rightarrow B=\frac{3}{2}A \\(8A + (2A+2B)) + 2(8A) + 4A &= (6A+2B) + 2(6A+4B) &\Rightarrow B=\frac{3}{2}A\end{align}
>
>  As we can see, our hypothesis not only holds for every provided equation - it also gives us a value for $B=\frac{3}{2}A$.
>
>  Given the value of $\text{Elephant} = 4A=8$, we can therefore calculate that
>
>  $$A = 2, \quad B = 3$$
>
>  Giving us a final answer for the pegasus of
>
>  $$\text{Pegasus} = 4A + 2B = 4\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3 = 14$$

Comment: Very good! (Except it's not a unicorn, but a pegasus :)

Comment: @Lezzup I clearly should read up on my mythology a bit before doing math ;) Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Nice job! I wonder whether this is intentional, but the number of letter in the animal names fit the equations, well, almost. Only swallow and half dragonfly don't make sense. If it's intentional, it's a great red herring in the puzzle! @Lezzup